# Combine key-chord and an input method

Tags: emacs

I would like to be able to use simultaneously [`key-chord`](http://www.emacswiki.org/KeyChord)
and an input method such as `rfc1345`.

Presently I use

> <kbd>C-x RET C-M-\</kbd>  <kbd>rfc1234 RET</kbd>

to activate the input method.

and

> <kbd>M-x</kbd>  <kbd>key-chord-mode RET</kbd>  <kbd>M-x</kbd>  <kbd>key-chord-mode RET</kbd>  (yes, two times)

to re-activate key-chord.

This switch is rather cumbersome. Any idea about how to have them both ativated? Or maybe a way to switch more quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in function `toggle-input-method`, bound to <kbd>C-\</kbd> by default that conveniently allows to switch from the set input method and key-chord support.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me (I didn't write it, just got from some other source - don't remember where)

I just did some adjustments for my needs...

```
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
(setq default-input-method "portuguese-prefix")

(defvar use-default-input-method t)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'use-default-input-method)

(defun activate-default-input-method ()
  (interactive)
  (if use-default-input-method
      (progn
        (set-input-method default-input-method)
        (activate-input-method default-input-method))
    (inactivate-input-method))
  (key-chord-mode t))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'activate-default-input-method)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'activate-default-input-method)
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'activate-default-input-method)

(defun inactivate-default-input-method ()
  (setq use-default-input-method nil)
  (key-chord-mode t))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'inactivate-default-input-method)

(activate-default-input-method)
```

In the last line, you can define the hooks that won't use the default input method, but key-chord-mode will also be set on.

Answer (score 0):

Does this function do what you want:

```
(defun my-whatever ()
  (interactive)
  "Doc string goes here."
  (activate-input-method "rfc1234")
  (key-chord-mode nil)
  (key-chord-mode nil))
```

I'm not sure what you have <kbd>C-M-\</kbd> bound to, but if it's bound to `activate-input-method`, I think this does the equivalent of your key presses.

Obviously, you would bind this function to a key sequence of your choosing.

Comment: I tried it but I get an error message :
> activate-input-method: Can't activate input method `rfc1234'

<kbd>C-x RET C-M-\</kbd> is the default for `set-input-method`.

Changing `activate` to `set` raises the same error message.

Also I would like to be able to toggle between both mehtods (if they cannot work together). I can define a similar command doing the reverse action but then I will have to use another key.